# Django Oscar Adaptive Paypal Payment

Tags: django, python-2.7, paypal, django-oscar

In my oscar application django needs adaptive parallel oscar payment procedure.

Can anyone tell how to integrate with Adaptive Parallel Paypal method into Normal Paypal. I have integrated Paypal PayFlow and Express methods.

Any tutorial references ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [paypal rest sdk](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK)

Install using pip

```
pip install paypalrestsdk
```

Comment: Can you create a tutorial for this?